# Как на WordPress передать переменную в functions.php, которую объявил в файле записи single-other.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как на wp передать переменную в functions.php, которую объявил в файле записи single-other.php?

Файл single-other.php

```
$GLOBALS['my_wp_related_posts'] = wp_related_posts();
```

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_helloy', 'helloy');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_helloy', 'helloy');

педаю аяксом в js результат 
function helloy( ) {

$GLOBALS['my_wp_related_posts'];

}
```

single-other.php

```
 <?php
получаю релевантные посты для данного
    $GLOBALS['my_wp_related_posts'] = wp_related_posts();


    ?>
```

Comment: Ну так и использовать: `global $my_wp_related_posts`. Только в каком месте. Просто в теле functions.php работать не будет, потому что single-other.php вызывается позднее. Код покажите.